# Sendgrid Header exception silently fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sendgrid

I am trying to send emails using **SendGrid C# SMTPAPI**. I've run into a problem which I can't seem to find any solution. My SendGridMessage header throws and exception and silently fails ..  see exception message below:

```
'((SendGrid.SmtpApi.Header)myMessage.Header).To' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'
```

Here is my code (Which is almost the same as the documentation)

```
    public static void SendAccountConfirmationEmail(string recipient)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the email object first, then add the properties.
            var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
            myMessage.AddTo(recipient);
            myMessage.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APP_EMAIL"], "RC2 FIT");
            myMessage.Subject = "Testing the SendGrid Library";
            myMessage.Text = "Hello World!";

            //Create a Web transport, using API Key (preferred)
            var transportWeb = new Web(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SENDGRID_API_KEY"]);

            // Send the email.
            transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {   
            System.Diagnostic.Debug.Writeline(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

No exception is being catch in my *Try catch* block and email is not being delivered to the recipient.

Comment: Just checking... you have put code in the `catch`, right?

Comment: Yeah I had:  System.Diagnostic.Debug.Writeline(e.Message) which I just forgot to copy I will edit.

Comment: Figured as much, but always good to check!  ;)

Comment: Check the formats of your "to" and "from" email addresses: `Test Person <test@person.com>`. Can you check the values of `recipient` and `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APP_EMAIL"]`?

Comment: I am sorry for the delay. I've been struggling with this since then. Both of the format are good.

Comment: I really think that `recipient` is not in the correct format. The exception being thrown seems to suggest that it is not in a correct format, either `email@address.com` or `Test Person <email@address.com>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the following method of using SendGrid's C# library instead? Just need to define `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SENDGRID_API_USER"]`.

```
using SendGridMail;
using SendGridMail.Transport;

public static void SendAccountConfirmationEmail(string recipient)
{
    try
    {
        SendGrid mail = SendGrid.GetInstance();
        mail.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APP_EMAIL"], "RC2 FIT");
        mail.AddTo(recipient);
        mail.Subject = "Testing the SendGrid Library";
        mail.Text = "Hello world!";

        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SENDGRID_API_USER"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SENDGRID_API_KEY"]);
        var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);
        transportWeb.Deliver(mail);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {   
        System.Diagnostic.Debug.Writeline(e.Message);
    }
}
```